# How can I access the Iframe content elements in mootools?

Tags: mootools

```
myIFrame = new IFrame({
    id: 'iframe_content',
    src: '/iframe_src/'
});
console.dir(myIFrame);
var n = new Element('div', {
    style: {
        'width': '100px',
        'height': "100px",
        'border': '1px solid red'
    }
});

myIFrame.inject(document.body);
console.log("innerhtml", myIFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
console.dir(myIFrame.contentDocument.body);
n.inject(myIFrame.contentDocument.body);
```

the div is not injected to the iframe , and any element in Ifrane cannot be accessed.
How can i do this in mootools 1.4.0 or MooTools 1.2

Answer (score 3):

this is a little more complex when it's about mixed content, i.e. content from `src=` and additional DOM elements built on the fly.

the iframe will have a `load` event which fires when the src content is picked up.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/AEP8T/

```
var myIFrame = new IFrame({
    id: 'iframe_content',
    src: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/',
    styles: {
        width: 640,
        height: 480
    },
    events: {
        load: function() {

            var n = new Element('div', {
                text: "hai there",
                styles: {
                    'width': '100px',
                    'height': "100px",
                    'border': '1px solid red'
                }
            });

            n.inject(this.contentDocument.body);

        }
    }
}).inject(document.body);
```

this will only work if the src and embed context are on the same domain/port etc.